# Replacing multiple items(commas, periods, etc.) in SQL code

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the code that I am using currently, I am trying to replace commas and periods in my database but right now it is only doing one or the other. Thanks

```
(Case when dim.obligorname like '%,%' then Replace(DIM.[ObligorName], ',', ' ') 
           Else case when dim.obligorname like '%.%' then Replace(DIM.[ObligorName], '.', ' ')
            Else Dim.ObligorName end end) as Obligorname,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
Replace( Replace(DIM.[ObligorName], ',', ' '), '.', ' ')
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just try something like this:

```
UPDATE myTable DIM
  SET DIM.[ObligorName] = 
    Replace(Replace(DIM.[ObligorName], ',', ' '), '.', ' ')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!